# Only one core is functioning under Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 for new HP Omen laptop 12th intel CPU i7-12700H,alder lake

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, ubuntu-drivers

I recently bought an HP Omen i7-12700H laptop and installed Ubuntu 18.04. After solving the wifi adapter problem, I found that only one core is functioning which should be 14? Could someone help, this is the first time I ever encountered this kind of problem

Comment: The GPU is nvidia 3050TI

Comment: I have seen this one core problem on a new Ryzen, which needed acpi=0 to even boot, but all fixed with a firmware update.

Comment: the 12th generation still hasn't good support even with new experimental kernels let alone with a 4 years old release! Honestly, why 18.04?

Comment: You have to try booting latest 22.04 LTS live development disk from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-amd64.iso .

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the kernel to 5.16 solves one core functioning problem. I got 14 core now, but there still exist a lot of problems...Hope, 22.04 could solve, well I will still go with 20.04 now